# Compress a string within Aura to limit the size of URL parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

**Question**: Is it possible to compress and decompress(or encoding/decoding) a string(or a large JSON) within an Aura component that has to be passed via URL parameters using Salesforce standard libraries ([EncodingUtil class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm)) ?

**Scenario**: I have an Lightning Aura comp on an object detail page that contains few weblinks. Clicking on any of these links would open a subtab (using `WorkspaceAPI`) where I am setting Pagereference.State value with some values from the parent component. As our application is growing with more data elements, so does the Pagereference.State. To reduce the overall State parameters, I am trying to explore ways to decrease the length of the parameters to hold same data, but transfer in compressed approach.

**Findings**: In my research, we would need some JS libraries to do the heavy lifting on the decoding/encoding aspect. But, these could pose some security concerns as we would be relying on some external sources.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

EncodingUtil doesn't have any kind of compression features. Compression in Apex is usually accomplished via third-party code, such as [Zippex](https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex). Client-side compression can be achieved with something like [lz-string](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/). Note that in Salesforce, code hosted off-platform is forbidden in Aura and LWC; you would instead save the code as a Static Resource or as a component library in Aura or LWC. At no point can you rely on external resources outside your control, so there is zero security risk.